# React-Native init - Cocoapods was resolved

Tags: ruby, react-native, cocoapods

if i run "npx react-native init testApp" i get the following error. What should i do to resolve this error?

```
An error occurred while installing nkf (0.2.0), and Bundler cannot continue.

In Gemfile:
  cocoapods was resolved to 1.14.3, which depends on
    xcodeproj was resolved to 1.24.0, which depends on
      CFPropertyList was resolved to 3.0.7, which depends on
        nkf
error Installing pods failed. This doesn't affect project initialization and you can safely proceed. 
However, you will need to install pods manually when running iOS, follow additional steps in "Run instructions for iOS" section.

✖ Installing Ruby Gems
```

Comment: Same is happening to me, were you able to resolve this?

Comment: Sorry, Not fixed yet

Answer (score 1):

What Ruby version is installed on your system?

I was getting exactly the same error. After hours of trying to get this thing to work I discovered that the **react-native v0.71 toolset expects Ruby version 2.7.6**

Current version of React Native as of the time I'm writing this answer (0.73) specifies no specific ruby version through .ruby_version file. But switching to that specific version solved my problem

So I believe using something like rbenv or asdf to switch to that specific version of ruby (2.7.6) might solve your problem as it solved mine.

So, assuming you have Homebrew installed, run:

```
$ brew install rbenv
$ rbenv install 2.7.6
```

And then you can switch your ruby version either locally or globally

```
$ rbenv global 2.7.6
```

Don't forget to **restart your shell**, now check for ruby version:

```
$ ruby -v
```

Now you can install cocoapods and the project dependencies properly.
I suggest that you **recreate your project**.

You can also install cocoapods via `gem`, `cd` into the `ios` folder and run `bundle install && bundle exec pod install` and it should work as well.

Comment: And after that I ran into another error. It might be related or not, but "FlipperKit" (dependency installed as pod) has something wrong with importing OpenSSL (dependency of dependency) when using case sensitive APFS. Maybe I'll end up reinstalling macOS using case insensitive APFS.